# c++ linked list class with header class

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to implement single linked list with a header class but i am also trying making information and pointer of linked list private and compiler says me

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment
>                            pred->Next()=temp->Next();

What's the wrong with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class IntSLLNode{
        private:
            int info;
            IntSLLNode * next;
        public:
                IntSLLNode(){
                        next=0;
                }
                IntSLLNode(int el,IntSLLNode *ptr=0){
                        info=el;
                        next=ptr;
                }
        int Info(){return info;}
        IntSLLNode * Next(){return next;}
};
IntSLLNode * head,* tail;//header structure
class IntSLList{
        IntSLList(){
                head=0; tail=0;
        }
    public:
        void addToHead(const int&);
        void addToTail(const int &);
        int deleteFromHead();
        int deleteFromTail();
        void deleteNode(int&);
        void listele();
};
void IntSLList::addToHead(const int &el){
        head=new IntSLLNode(el,head);
        if(tail==0)
                tail=head;
}
void IntSLList::addToTail(const int &el){
        if(tail==0){
                head=tail=new IntSLLNode(el,head);
        }
        else{
                tail->Next()=new IntSLLNode(el);
                tail=tail->Next();
        }
}
int IntSLList::deleteFromHead(){
        if(head==0){
                cout<<"No value such that";
                return -1;
        }
        int el=head->Info();
        IntSLLNode * temp=head;
        if(head==tail){
                head=tail=0;
        }
        else{
                head=head->Next();
        }
        delete temp;
        return el;
}
```

Comment: `Next()` returns a copy of the pointer. Modifying only the copy doesn't make much sense, which is what the compiler tries to tell you.

Comment: I hope this is not production code and you are just learning about C++. This implementation is inferior to `std::list` in so many ways that it has to be a learning tool, is it?

Comment: To change the private data the `Node` could have a `Follow` or `LinkTo` member that rearranges pointers. Which one you need depends on how you see the list organized.

Comment: @wigy yes i am just trying to learn c++ and this is my first code test about it,but now i need a solution more than contempt

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to be mean, but I saw too much C++ code in production that was really dangerous to shave off some nanoseconds here and there. If you are new to C++ it is a really good exercise what you are doing, congratulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment to a return *value* of a function/method would not do anything useful. You can only assign to a *reference* of a value returned by a function.

```
class IntSLLNode{
    ...
    int& Info(){return info;}
    IntSLLNode*& Next(){return next;}
};
```

But then, it would break encapsulation of that node and would allow any external code to change the linking of your nodes in the list by mistake. Personally I would hide the whole node class into the list class and provide methods to access `Info()` values to code outside this file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand the difference between lvalue and rvalue. In simple words, **lvalue** is something that can be assigned (variable etc.) while **rvalue** is a temporary value (just like the one that you are returning here:
 `IntSLLNode * Next(){return next;}`)
Then, by trying to assign something to rvalue, you get an error.
As a solution here, you could make your `IntSLLNode * next;` public or return a reference to this class member in your Next() function.